# Hashids unique space

Tags: java, hashids

I was wondering if I'm experiencing a bug, or have just run into a limitation of the Hashids algorithm.

I'm using a custom alphabet, which consists of all uppercase letters, minus "O" and "I" and digits 2 - 9.

After generating several million hashes, I noticed that duplicates started to appear. I'm confused by this, especially since Hashids claims that duplicates are not possible since the algorithm is simply a hex version of an integer. And so long as the integers remain unique (such as counting up forever), so will the hashes.

Does a custom alphabet make it more likely for duplicates to appear? Also, I was expecting the number of unique hashes for my alphabet to be: 32^7 = 34,359,738,368. Before my counter hit this number, the generated hashids grew from 7 characters long to 8.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Edit: another rather strange anomaly: after generating 10647 hashes, the rest (2.9 million plus) either start with a K or an X. I'm beginning to think the custom alphabet plus the length of the salt affect how the letters get shuffled.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Paulpro, Sorry, Java. I've added it as a tag too. Also, using version 1.0.0 of Hashids

Comment: *"After generating several million hashes"* - How much have you tried to generate exactly?

Comment: @GergelyBacso: 4.9 million.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding the letters and digits I,O,0,1 back into the alphabet being used. With the increase in length of the alphabet, the rotation calculated by Hashids was affected. I simply filtered out any output that included an I,O,0 or 1 using a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

have same problem, just try this :

```
var hashids = new Hashids("BSomeoneNameN161179IBRB46", 5, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890");

var id = hashids.encode(1234567);
var numbers = hashids.decode(id);
```

changing salt by deleting last 5 characters one by one, just showing same result.

making salt not more than 20 chars seems solve the problem.